# Pandas Left Merge with xlsx with CSV producing null value columns in output

Tags: python, excel, csv, pandas, merge

I am using Python 3.4, Pandas 0.16.2 and Jupyter Notebook as my IDE.

I am importing the following two dataframes as follows:

```
Lookup = pd.read_excel("LookupMergeOutput.xlsx")

Concatenated = pd.read_csv('Concatenated.csv', error_bad_lines = False, na_values='', iterator=True,  chunksize=1000)
data = pd.concat([chunk for chunk in Concatenated], ignore_index=True)
```

**Data**

***Lookup*** dataframe spec: 23353 rows 8; 8 columns

```
Columns:          Dtype:

LOGINNAME         object
FIRSTNAME         object
LASTNAME          object
ID_y               int64
CREATEUSERID       int64
REVISIONUSERID     int64
BEGINDATE         object
ENDDATE           object
```

***data*** dataframe spec: 23653 rows; 667 columns

The column of interest for the merge in this dataframe is `REFERENCE_ID` with

```
data.REFERENCE_ID.dtype
```

as 'object'

The columns to merge on are `ID_y` and `REFERENCE_ID` (in the ***data*** dataframe). The columns in ***Lookup*** contain unique value counts (eg. 265926639 etc).

The ***data*** dataframe has unique values, but also repeating instances of an an entry (for example, three instances of 265946567. Moreover, there are error strings with the following caricature: `421D6158-22D4-EDAC-0DEA-33B1FB5CC7AF`.

**Goal**:
To merge ***Lookup*** and ***data*** on the to key columns `ID_y` and `REFERENCE_ID`, respectively.

***References and prior search for answers but with little fruit to bear:

1. [Left merge without reindexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25793709/pandas-dataframe-left-merge-without-reindexing)
2. [Conditional Merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060562/conditional-merge-for-csv-files-using-python-pandas)
3. [Chris Albon's Tutorial](http://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_join_merge_dataframe.html)
4. [Merging multiple dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668427/pandas-joining-multiple-dataframes-on-columns)
5. [Data Carpentry's Review](http://www.datacarpentry.org/python-ecology/04-merging-data)

What I have attempted so far:

```
merged_left = pd.merge(left=Lookup,right=data, how='left', left_on='ID_y', right_on='REFERENCE_ID')
```

This returns all of the ***Lookup*** data but all 667 columns of the ***data*** dataframe come back as null values.

In theory, if there are common numbers in the two "key" columns, the data from the ***data*** dataframe to match. My hypothesis is either that there is a data type conflict or because there are repeating numbers in the ***data*** dataframe, that the merge is not taking place. I want to avoid dropping the duplicates or multiple instances of keys in the ***data*** column as this may have valid data.

I have also tried to rename the `ID_y`columnname to `REFERENCE_ID` and perform a merge as follows:

```
Lookup=Lookup.rename(columns = {'ID_y':'REFERENCE_ID'})
```

This produces a `null` dataframe (just columns, but no values). I have also attempted to set the index as `ID_y` and `REFERENCE_ID` and then perform the merge on the index:

```
Lookup = Lookup.set_index('ID_y')
data = data.set_index('REFERENCE_ID')

merged_on_index = pd.merge(Lookup,data, left_index=True,right_index=True)
```

I receive the following traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-3909fd759082> in <module>()
----> 1 pd.merge(AgentLookup,data,left_index=True,right_index=True)

C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py in merge(left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy)
     36                          right_index=right_index, sort=sort, suffixes=suffixes,
     37                          copy=copy)
---> 38     return op.get_result()
     39 if __debug__:
     40     merge.__doc__ = _merge_doc % '\nleft : DataFrame'

C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py in get_result(self)
    184 
    185     def get_result(self):
--> 186         join_index, left_indexer, right_indexer = self._get_join_info()
    187 
    188         ldata, rdata = self.left._data, self.right._data

C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py in _get_join_info(self)
    257         if self.left_index and self.right_index:
    258             join_index, left_indexer, right_indexer = \
--> 259                 left_ax.join(right_ax, how=self.how, return_indexers=True)
    260         elif self.right_index and self.how == 'left':
    261             join_index, left_indexer, right_indexer = \

C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py in join(self, other, how, level, return_indexers)
   2041             other = other.astype('O')
   2042             return this.join(other, how=how,
-> 2043                              return_indexers=return_indexers)
   2044 
   2045         _validate_join_method(how)

C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py in join(self, other, how, level, return_indexers)
   2054             else:
   2055                 return self._join_non_unique(other, how=how,
-> 2056                                              return_indexers=return_indexers)
   2057         elif self.is_monotonic and other.is_monotonic:
   2058             try:

C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py in _join_non_unique(self, other, how, return_indexers)
   2125 
   2126         left_idx, right_idx = _get_join_indexers([self.values], [other.values],
-> 2127                                                  how=how, sort=True)
   2128 
   2129         left_idx = com._ensure_platform_int(left_idx)

C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py in _get_join_indexers(left_keys, right_keys, sort, how)
    459 
    460     # get left & right join labels and num. of levels at each location
--> 461     llab, rlab, shape = map(list, zip( * map(fkeys, left_keys, right_keys)))
    462 
    463     # get flat i8 keys from label lists

TypeError: type object argument after * must be a sequence, not map
```

At this point in time, I at a loss as to what would be the best strategy. I welcome feedback on next steps.

Comment: What exactly happens when you run the merged_left line? Which columns are null etc

Comment: @AustinC All 667 columns of the "data" dataframe's columns contain null values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your join fields are different data types. `REFERENCE_ID` as an object type and `ID_y` as a numeric `int64` type. Interestingly, the `object` dtype in pandas is a NumPy [ndarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018654/strings-in-a-dataframe-but-dtype-is-object) which holds pointers to variable-length string items. Also, `object` is the most general of the data types when imported data contains both strings and numbers.

Consider converting the join fields to same data types using [astype](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html). Of course, strings tend to be most permissive allowing various characters like hyphens.

String conversion:

```
data['REFERENCE_ID'] = data['REFERENCE_ID'].apply(str)  # NOTICE APPLY HERE
LookUp['ID_y'] = LookUp['ID_y'].astype(str)
```

Numeric conversion:

```
data['REFERENCE_ID'] = data['REFERENCE_ID'].astype(int)
```

Combination:

```
data['REFERENCE_ID'] = data['REFERENCE_ID'].astype(str).astype(int)
LookUp['ID_y'] = LookUp['ID_y'].astype(str).astype(int)
```

Comment: The coversion to str for both columns worked! Thank you!